# Camel breakup route

Tags: routes, apache-camel

I have a `RouteBuilder` class that has grown quite large with many Direct Routes: **`from("direct:...")`**.

Each Route is performing a specific type of enrichment of the body.

The `RouteBuilder` works fine but it would be nice to break it up into a few separate classes where each class is specific to the type of enrichment being performed.

The classes would be a part of the same workflow, just defined in separate classes.

Is this possible? If so, can anyone point me to examples?

Comment: Hi! As far as I know you can add many routebuilder classes to a single camel context and they can still use `from("direct:...")` as long as they are within the same context. However, you can use `from("direct-vm:...)` to communicate between camel contexts as long as they are within the same JVM. For example, communicating between different bundles in the same OSGi container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Screwtape already commented, you can have as many `RouteBuilder` classes as you want to build 1 `CamelContext`. Because you use [Direct Routes](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html), they need to be in the same `CamelContext` what is normally true if they are in the same deployment unit.

If you use [Spring-Boot and the Camel-Starter](http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html) the `RouteBuilder`s are even auto-discovered if you declare them as `@Component`.

A [simple example with multiple Direct Routes](https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-apache-camel-core-3) in different `RouteBuilder`s

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know the answer to this too, but I haven't been able to find any examples either - so I tried doing this as a proof-of-concept (using Camel 3):

RouteBuilderA.java

```java
public class RouteBuilderA extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from("timer:myTimer?fixedRate=true&period=1000")
            .setBody().constant("ROUTE A")
            .log("${body}")
            .to(RouteBuilderB.INPUT);
    }
}
```

RouteBuilderB.java

```java
public class RouteBuilderB extends RouteBuilder {
    public static final String INPUT = "direct:input";

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(INPUT)
                .setBody().constant("ROUTE B")
                .log("${body}");
    }
}
```

MainRouteBuilder.java

```java
public class MainRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        getContext().addRoutes(new RouteBuilderA());
        getContext().addRoutes(new RouteBuilderB());
    }
}
```

I've not looked into the drawbacks of using this setup, i.e. what it means for error handling, Message Exchange Patterns etc. but this seems to work for a start.